# SudsLibrary in Robot Framework: Getting & Setting object attributes

Tags: soap, robotframework, suds

I am working with the SudsLibrary for Robot Framework. Below is the Rq/Rs for the webservice I'm testing. You will also find the Robot Framework info and my comment on what's going on.

REQUEST

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sec="http://localhost/ABC/Services/Security/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sec:AuthUser>
         <sec:userName>MyAdmin</sec:userName>
         <sec:password>Password123</sec:password>
      </sec:AuthUser>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

RESPONSE

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.ompum-open.org/wss/2004/01/ompum-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.ompum-open.org/wss/2004/01/ompum-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <soap:Header>
      ...
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <AuthUserResponse xmlns="http://localhost/ABC/Services/Security/">
         <AuthTicket>k3l5d9k6-3z53-8765-b512-df09as87</AuthTicket>
      </AuthUserResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SudsLibrary

*** Test Case ***
Check App Auth Ticket
    Create Soap Client    http://localhost/Services/Authentication.asmx?wsdl
    ${WSDLobj}    Create Wsdl Object    AuthUser
    Set Wsdl Object Attribute    ${WSDLobj}    userName    MyAdmin
    Set Wsdl Object Attribute    ${WSDLobj}    password    Password123
    ${result}    Call Soap Method    AuthUser    ${WSDLobj}
    log    Result: ${result}
    # Now get the specific element from the response
    ${AuthVal}    Get Wsdl Object Attribute    ${result}    AuthTicket
    log    Auth Ticket: ${AuthVal}
```

Everything is successful in my test case `Check App Auth Ticket` until I call the SudsLibrary `Get Wsdl Object Attribute` keyword. The following error occurs: `ValueError: Object must be a WSDL object (suds.sudsobject.Object)`. Why would I get an error when the object is created and is called successfully?

When I print out the `${result}` variable, it is the value for `AuthVal`. However, I am wanting to explicitly extract a specific value / element from the web service response. I have other web service responses that will require me to parse this data for my end to end testing.